# Customizing the izpack installer with a Griffon app

Tags: izpack, griffon

I've tried using the installer plugin to create an izpack install and although I can create an installer I haven't had any luck configuring the izpack installer.

I looked at the sample SwingPad application and copied some files across to my project (and modified the values in installer.xml):

- ./src/installer/izpack/resources/installer.xml
- ./src/installer/izpack/resources/README.html
- ./scripts/_Events.groovy

But this has no effect whatsoever.

I'm using griffon 1.2.0.

Anyone have any suggestions about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the installer plugin that prevents it from honoring your customizations. I've filed http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-607 to take care of it.

Comment: Thanks, I found I could run 'griffon list-plugin-updates' which showed me new versions were available, but is the correct way to upgrade a plugin to simply run 'griffon install-plugin installer 0.8'? i.e. specify the version - is there a way to 'upgrade all plugins'?

Comment: Yes, you can run "griffon list-plugin-updates --install=true" to install all updates. See http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/ref/Command%20Line/list-plugin-updates.html